# Why async () transform to async function () in Jest tests?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, jestjs, babel-jest

My jest test case is similar to:

```
test('should update state.focus', async () => {
  let component = getComponent()
  component.setState({focus: true})
  expect(component.state().focus).toEqual(true)
  component.instance().handleBlur()

  await expect(component.state().focus).toEqual(false)
})
```

This works fine in local dev environment. However it fails on bamboo giving the following error:

```
test('should update state.focus', async function () {
                                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
  at handle (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:41:8)
  at process.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:47:3)
  at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
```

I am using jest - 20.0.3 and babel-jest 20.0.3

Comment: Can you add the entire body of the function

Comment: I updated the body above

Comment: I meant the function which contains an error

Comment: I've updated both the test function and build error to include everything I've got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I could solve it by installing the `babel-preset-es2017` package and then use it in the `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2017"]
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks for saving me so much frustration!